# Why the terminal reported a "zsh: trace trap" error when running my program?

Tags: c, memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char *line = NULL;
size_t linecap = 0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  FILE *fp_in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  if (fp_in == NULL) {
    printf("error: cannot open file '%s'\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }
 // two files are the same.
  if (!(strcmp(argv[1], argv[2]))) {
    printf("Input and output file must differ\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  ssize_t length;
  FILE *fp_out = fopen(argv[2], "w");
  char *lines = (char *) malloc(1);

  while ((length = getline(&line, &linecap, fp_in)) > 0) {
    lines = (char *) realloc(lines, sizeof(lines) + length * sizeof(char));
    strcat(line, lines);  //make lines behind the new line
    strcpy(lines, line);  // turn the new string back into lines
}
  fprintf(fp_out, "%s", lines);
  free(lines);
  fclose(fp_in);
  fclose(fp_out);
  return 0;
}
```

The code is to read content of a file and reverse its line order then write into another file.
After executed, the shell issued:
**zsh: trace trap**.
Could someone gives me an explanation? Thanks!

Comment: HI. Welcome to SO. Please read the instructions about how to ask a question. If you provide a minimal, runnable program, you're much more likely to get the help you want. It's often too much to ask for people to guess from code fragments. Here you haven't even included the declaration of `line`, which is important.

Comment: can't definitively say without a [mre], but you're probably overwriting one of your buffers. `sizeof(lines)` and (probably) `sizeof(line)` don't do what you think. `lines` is a pointer, so `sizeof(lines)` returns the size of the _pointer_ (4 or 8 depending on your architecture), _not_ how many bytes it points to. So I'd guess you're `realloc`ing `lines` to 16, then invoking UB by `strcat`ing that unitialized memory to `line`, then maybe UB again by `strcpy`ing `line` into memory that may not be big enough to hold it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your core problem is this

```
lines = (char *) realloc(lines, sizeof(lines) + length * sizeof(char));
```

`sizeof(lines)` and `sizeof(line)` will both be 4 or 8 since they are both pointers

you can do

```
lines = (char *) realloc(lines, strlen(lines) + strlen(line) + 1);
```

since both are 0 terminated